# R: POSIXct conversion fails although local is set

Tags: r, timestamp, posix

I get NA's when trying to convert english dates from strings to POSIX. 
I am working on a german pc but I set my locale to US.

```
> Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_TIME")
[1] "English_United States.1252"

as.POSIXct("23-MAI-18 03:14:00",  
format="%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2018-05-23 03:14:00 CEST"

> as.POSIXct("23-MAY-18 03:14:00",  
format="%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S")
[1] NA
```

Comment: What yields the full `Sys.getlocale()`?

Comment: I played around with the locale some more. Now it reads:  `[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"` 
But it works now! I just thought LC_TIME is sufficient

Comment: That's great. Then you could describe the solution for the community and answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why but setting all locale settings with  `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")` solved it for me.